# Splainer - Change Color of JSON without Changing Root File

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, solr

If anyone has used SOLR and splainer.io http://splainer.io/# you know how it spits out your JSON objects in however you wrote them.

I need to color some of the words red.

For example, if one of my tags is >popularity.

I want the word popularity to show up red. is there any way to make some short script that i can just pop into the console of chrome, to avoid changing the file?

Or maybe there is an angular.js solution? 
I'm sllightly clueless

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide an url example to test ?

Comment: @Gonzalo.- its local, our firewall won't let you do anything useful with it, but here is the URL you would put into splainer [link](http://dc2-solrdev1.bnh.com:8983/solr/bh_catalog_current/bh_acc2?q=canon&fq=discontinued%3AN&fq=newused_status%3AN)